# How to combine ggplot and plotly graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I prepare a `data.frame` as follow;

```
  #create dataframe
  df <-data.frame(x = c(rnorm(300, 3, 2.5), rnorm(150, 7, 2)), # create random data
                  y = c(rnorm(300, 6, 2.5), rnorm(150, 2, 2)),
                  z = c(rnorm(300, 6, 2.5), rnorm(150, 2, 2)),
                  group = c(rep('A', 300), rep('B', 150))) # add two groups
```

The relationship between y and x is like below, when showing by `ggplot2`;

```
  #for y-x correlation by group with fit curve
  gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon", aes(alpha = ..level..,fill=group))+
    geom_smooth(method = 'loess')
  print(gg)
```

[image]

Then, I created `plot_ly` 3D figure as follows;

```
  #plot_ly 3D plot
  s = interp(x = df$x, y = df$y, z = df$z,duplicate = "mean") # prepare for plot_ly plot
  p <- plot_ly(x = s$x, y = s$y, z = s$z,colorscale = 'Jet')%>% # plot_ly
    add_surface()
```

, which created a graph as below;

[image]

Then, here is the question.
I would like to add the first `ggplot2` figure at the bottom of the second `plot_ly` figure, like as below;

[image]

Is there any way (function or package) to accomplish this with R?

Comment: Some [related content](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1650).